# Static typing of the parameters of a Generic type

Tags: python-3.x, generics, pydantic, pydantic-v2

If I have "factory" method, taking a class type and the relevant parameters to create a resource, is there a way to have static analysis of the parameters?

```py
from typing import Type

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Res(BaseModel):
    f: int
    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"


def factory[T](resource_type: Type[T], **kwargs) -> T:
    return resource_type(**kwargs)


factory(Res, f=3) # no problem!
factory(Res, f=3, g=4) # ValidationError, g is not allowed.
```

This works as expected at run time. I would love for pyright to notice statically that `g` is not a valid parameter to `Res`.

Is it at all possible? I am looking in the direction of [ParamSpecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec), but it does not help yet.

```py
def factory[T, **P](resource_type: Type[T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    return resource_type(**kwargs)
factory(Res, f=3) # says: Param spec "P@factory" has no bound value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typing.ParamSpec` should be the way to go. The error message says it all: the ParamSpec is not bound to any callable. Change the signature from `type[T]` to `Callable[P, T]`.

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, reveal_type

from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)
P = ParamSpec("P")


class Res(BaseModel):
    f: int

    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"


def factory(resource_type: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    return resource_type(*args, **kwargs)


reveal_type(factory(Res, f=3))  # Revealed type is "Res"
```

Comment: So easy (once I understood your answer), so powerful. Awesome, thanks!